# How can I fix the Keras.NET BadImageFormatException exception?

Tags: python, asp.net-core, keras, .net-core

I created a machine learning model with keras using python. I saved this model in a .h5 file and want to use that file in my ASP.NET Core API. To load the model I am using Keras.NET.

The problem I am encountering is that when I try to debug the application I get the following error:

```
  Message: 
    System.BadImageFormatException : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
  Stack Trace: 
    Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
    Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
    PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
    PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
    PythonEngine.Initialize()
    Keras.InstallAndImport(String module)
    <.cctor>b__27_0()
    Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
    Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
    Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    Lazy`1.get_Value()
    Keras.get_Instance()
    Sequential.ctor()
```

I have read about other people encountering this problem. They say that I should change my Platform Target to x64.

Doing that leads to the following error:

```
  Message: 
    System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'Project.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  Stack Trace: 
    ModelsTest.Test_models()
```

Now the rest of my tests are failing with a `BadImageFromatException`. This let me to think that python is installed as a 64 bit version and .NET Core as a 32 bit. To make sure this is not the case I reinstalled the 64 bit version of .NET Core but I keep getting the same error.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: have you a solution ?